# What does the Apple Neural Engine do?

Tags: macos, apple-m1

I can't find any useful documentation on what the Apple Neural Engine does specifically beyond "accelerate machine learning tasks across the Mac for things like video analysis, voice recognition, image processing, and more", which doesn't tell me much. Is it just another TPU? What architecture does it use? Does it have accelerators for any specific operations linear algebra operations? Do they have a CUDA-type language to actually use it?

Comment: There seems to be very little information about how exactly it works, but you can (only?) interface with it by using [CoreML](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml) which will use it if available.